# Is there a reason not to use the newest C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++14, standards, c++20

I have seen that the default standard in IDEs is usually not the newest released standard, not even the newest standard in the IDE.
For example JetBrains' Clion has C++20 and C++17 but the default option is C++14.

Is there a reason not to use the newest released standard?

Comment: If your compiler supports C++17 or C++20, you can use it.  Some compilers only have partial support for C++17 and C++20, so they default to C++14.

Comment: There could be various reasons to not use the newest standard. New features are less tested, and there probability that there is a bug related to them might be higher. Static analyzers to detect bugs might not work as good with the newer version as with older ones. Developers don’t know the new features that well so the probably of bugs could be higher, …

Comment: Use a compiler such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to compile C++ code. Choose an IDE capable of driving a recent GCC. Regarding C++, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read the documentation of your compiler, your IDE, your C++ variant, your linker

Comment: If one of your goals is to write portable C++ code that "just works everywhere" (or as close to everywhere as possible), then using features from the latest C++ standard can be a problem, because now your code won't compile on platforms that do not (yet) support the latest C++ standard.  And if you are doing your development and testing in a build environment that is set to use the latest C++ standard, you likely won't know that you have that problem right away, but rather only when you go to actually compile your code on an older platform; by then you may have a lot of code to rewrite.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As a general rule, use the latest standard if you can.

But, there are some reasons why you may in some situations choose to use an older one.

- Your code makes use of features that changed behaviour in newer standards or were removed outright. If you don't have time to update your code, compiling for the older standard is reasonable.
- Your tool-chain may not implement the new standard correctly. There could be known bugs that force you to stick to an older one.
- You need to support multiple compilers on multiple platforms and not all combinations support the new standard yet.
- You need to be binary compatible with code built by an older compiler for an older standard and you don't have the source to recompile it. In that case you may be forced to use the same old compiler and language standard to ensure ABI compatibility.
- Internal company politics may mandate a specific version for arbitrary reasons.
- Certification requirements may mandate use of a specific compiler and/or language version.
- Familiarity with the new features may be low on your team, so using them may increase the risk of bugs.

Etc (I've seen all of the above happen in real life btw)..

Comment: Certification requirements don't mandate a compiler/language version. They do require documented verification that the code, when built, produces the required effects. For high criticality code, that includes verifying (e.g. by examining machine code) that the output from the compiler meets requirements of the original code. Verification for one version of the compiler (or other tool-chain components) does not automatically give verification for any other version. The cost of re-verification - and documentation - can be significant when updating to a new compiler.

Comment: Notice though that user might select standard, even in recent ones than older ones, so most reasons provided are unrelated to default choice of compilers. Reasons from comment seems more accurate.